# What is the proper way to use the active target synchronization Start() Complete() Post() Wait() on a mpi4py Window?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

Why does this not work?

```
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
group = comm.Get_group()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

mpi_datatype = MPI.DOUBLE # use this for Allocate()
np_datatype = numpy.float64

if rank == 1:
    a = numpy.empty(9, dtype=np_datatype)
    window = MPI.Win.Create(a, comm=comm)
elif rank == 0:
    window = MPI.Win.Create(None, comm=comm)

if rank == 1:
    window.Post(group=group)
    window.Wait()
elif rank == 0:
    b = numpy.full(9, 1.5, dtype=np_datatype)
    window.Start(group=group)
    window.Put(b, target_rank=1)
    window.Complete()

if rank == 1:
    val = a[0] # should be 1.5 if Put() worked...
```

I noticed that if I remove window.Complete() and window.Wait() functions, the two rank processes are able to print the numpy.empty() value, meaning they were able to run until completion - incorrectly however.

I could not find an example of how to use the active target sync functions in mpi4py online.  BTW, I got the Fence() and Lock() sync functions to work.  But I believe this method will be faster given my actual program will have rank processes sync in pairs (I dont want to sync globally). Any advise welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Start(group=EXPOSURE_EPOCH_PROCESS_GROUP) and Post(group=ACCESS_EPOCH_PROCESS_GROUP)

```
import numpy
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
group = comm.Get_group()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

mpi_datatype = MPI.DOUBLE # use this for Allocate()
np_datatype = numpy.float64

if rank == 1:
    a = numpy.empty(9, dtype=np_datatype)
    window = MPI.Win.Create(a, comm=comm)
elif rank == 0:
    window = MPI.Win.Create(None, comm=comm)

if rank == 1:
    g1 = comm.group.Incl([0])
    window.Post(group=g1)
    window.Wait()
elif rank == 0:
    g2 = comm.group.Incl([1])
    b = numpy.full(9, 1.5, dtype=np_datatype)
    window.Start(group=g2)
    window.Put(b, target_rank=1)
    window.Complete()

if rank == 1:
    val = a[0] # val = 1.5
```